# Hacer un populate de un array con mongodb y nodejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Buenas Gente como están? desearía que puedan ayudarme, estoy haciendo una API con Express y MongoDB

```
const ligaSchema = new Schema({
  name:String,
  imgUrl:String,
  equipos:[{
    ref: "Equipo",
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }]
}
```

tengo el siguiente modelo de ligas, el cual tiene un array de id's de equipos, el problema viene cuando intento hacer la consulta con el populate a equipos:

```
export const getLigas = async (req, res) => {
  const ligas = await Ligas.find()
  .populate('equipos')
  res.json(ligas);
}
```

esta consulta, me devuelve el array de equipos vacío, pero si hago la consulta sin el populate, me devuelve el array con los respectivos id

```
"_id": "63d6e7b05d0ee37943d7c550",
"name": "Boca Juniors",
"liga": {
    "_id": "63d6e4284375c6f34a3a4d68",
    "name": "Liga Argentina",
    "imgUrl": "http://localhost:4000/public/1675027496843-180084245-LPF.png",
    "equipos": [
        "63d6e4284375c6f34a3a4d68",
        "63d6e4284375c6f34a3a4d68"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-01-29T21:24:56.869Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-29T21:40:26.515Z"
},
"imgUrl": "http://localhost:4000/public/1675028400433-543572298-Club_Atletico_Boca_Juniors-logo-0885F318F0-seeklogo.com.png",
"createdAt": "2023-01-29T21:40:00.495Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-01-29T21:40:00.495Z"
},
```

pero lo que necesito  es que haga el populate en cada uno de los equipos, asi logro obtener sus datos, no se si es que al ser un array de id, el populate debe manejarse distinto.
Ojala puedan ayudarme!
Un Abrazo.

Comment: Revisa exactamente como estás almacenando los datos... quizas estás almacenando los equipos como una lista de strings y no como una lista de `ObjectId`?

Answer (score -1):

El problema es probablemente que la propiedad ref en tu esquema de equipo quizas no la estableciste correctamente. La propiedad ref debería tener el nombre de la colección que estás relacionando, en este caso, "Equipo".

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]